# Is a USA employer required to provide worker's compensation insurance to a contractor if the contractor signed away the insurance?

Tags: united-states, contract-law, insurance, maryland, contractor

Is a USA employer required to provide worker's compensation to a contractor if the contractor signed away that insurance and said such employer is not required to provide?

Comment: These sorts of things are generally determined by state law.  Do you have a particular state in mind?  Regardless, this sort of thing is usually not something you can eliminate by contract, just as an employee cannot sign away the right to be paid at least minimum wage.

Comment: @phoog This particular question is indeed very state specific and would vary a lot from state to state. I wouldn't even hazard a guess as to the majority rule. Also, worker's comp is often required by contract or construction loan financing even if not required by state law.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Employers must insure employees, not independent contractors

However, whether the relationship is employer-employee or principal-contractor is not for the parties to specify.

See:

- [Indepdendent/Contractor vs Regular Employee](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/18339/344)
- [What is the liability for a contractor / employee asked to create tax submission](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/70605/344)
- https://law.stackexchange.com/a/44718/344
- https://law.stackexchange.com/a/47034/344
- [Is an independent contractor liable?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/56116/344)